# Не правильно работает функция std::snprintf

Tags: c++

Мне нужно чтобы выводилось `Score: 0:0`, а выводится так `Score: 0`. Делаю так:

```
std::snprintf(textBuffer, sizeof(textBuffer), "Score: %d",  currentPlayerScore, ": %d", currentEnemyScore);
```

И так пробовал:

```
std::snprintf(textBuffer, sizeof(textBuffer), "Score: %d", ": %f", currentPlayerStrikerScore, currentEnemyStrikerScore);
```

Но тут какая-то лабуда совсем выводится. Подскажите как правильно выводить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя [по описанию функции](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), у нее должен быть такой формат:

```
int snprintf( char* buffer, std::size_t buf_size, const char* format, ... );
```

Тогда:

```
std::snprintf(textBuffer, sizeof(textBuffer), "Score: %d:%d", currentPlayerStrikerScore, currentEnemyStrikerScore);
```